# I make changes in wordpress but nothing changes

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using wordpress to develop a website.

I am using my own html template instead of wordpress themes, which has css file also.

When I try to make some html changes in it through the dashboard of wordpress, it doesn't change.

Why it does not happen?

Is wordpress doesn't support html tags sometimes?

Or is the html tags that I use, clashes with css?

code of index page is here.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">
<div id="inner_content">
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
<div id="content_top">
<div id="business_strategy">

<div id="heading_outer">
<p class="main_heading">Business</p>
<p class="main_heading1">Strategy</p>
</div><!---heading_outer--->

<div id="business_image"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/inner_image.gif" alt="image" /></div><!---business_image--->

<div id="des">
<p>Owing to its competitive stand in the world India has moved rapidly. There is ample reason...</p>
<span class="read_more"><a href="?page_id=56">Read More</a></span></div><!---des--->
</div><!---business_strategy--->


<div id="business_planning">
<div id="heading_outer">
<p class="main_heading">Business</p>
<p class="main_heading1">Planning</p>
</div><!---heading_outer--->

<div id="business_image"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/inner_image.gif" alt="image" /></div><!---business_image--->

<div id="des">
<p>Owing to its competitive stand in the world India has moved rapidly. There is ample reason...</p>
<span class="read_more"><a href="?page_id=81">Read More</a></span></div><!---des--->
</div><!---business_planning--->


<div id="business_planning">
<div id="heading_outer">
<p class="main_heading">Business</p>
<p class="main_heading1">Result</p>
</div><!---heading_outer--->

<div id="business_image"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/inner_image.gif" alt="image" /></div><!---business_image--->

<div id="des">
<p>Owing to its competitive stand in the world India has moved rapidly. There is ample reason...</p>
<span class="read_more"><a href="?page_id=85">Read More</a></span></div><!---des--->
</div><!---business_planning--->

</div><!---content_top--->
<?php } ?>
<div id="content_bottom">

<div id="content_bottom_left">
<div id="content_bottom_intro">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
<h3 class="content_heading">Who We Are?</h3>
<?php } else { ?>
<h3 class="content_heading"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<?php } ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; /* rewind or continue if all posts have been fetched */ ?>
<?php else : ?>

<?php endif; ?>
</div><!---content_bottom_intro--->
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
<span class="line_bg"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/line_bg.gif" alt="image" /></span>

<div id="partners">
<h3>Clients</h3>
<div id="partners_logo"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/logos.gif" alt="image" style="margin-top:10px;" /></div>
<!---partners_logo--->
</div><!---channel_partners--->
<?php } ?>
</div><!---content_bottom_left--->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div><!---content_bottom--->
</div><!---inner_content--->
</div><!---content--->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and css is here.

```
/*
Theme Name: Business_template
Author: Ravneet Singh
*/





@charset "utf-8";

body{
width:100%;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
background-color:#2e6a92;
}

#main_outer{
width:100%;
float:left;
margin:auto;
}

#inner_outer{
width:900px;
float:none;
margin:auto;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

#menu{
background-image:url(images/menu_bg.gif);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:900px;
height:114px;
float:left;
margin:auto;
}

#menu ul{
margin-left:75px;
margin-top:-12px;
margin-bottom:10px;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}

#menu ul li{
list-style:none;
float:left;
}

#menu ul li a{
width:135px;
height:23px;
font-size:18px;
display:block;
color:#ffffff;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
text-align:right;
text-decoration:none;
}

#menu ul li a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}

#header{
width:900px;
height:203px;
float:left;
margin:auto;
background-image:url(images/header_bg.gif);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

#logo{
width:500px;
height:195px;
float:left;
margin:auto;
}

#header_image{
width:400px;
height:195px;
float:right;
margin:auto;
}

#content{
width:900px;
float:left;
margin:auto;
background-color:#FFFFFF
}

#inner_content{
width:890px;
float:left;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
}

#content_top{
width:880px;
float:left;
margin:auto;
}

#business_strategy{
width:290px;
height:173px;
float:left;
margin:auto;
background-color:#d7d4c5;
}

#heading_outer{
width:136px;
height:100px;
float:left;
margin:auto;
}

.main_heading{
color:#740a07;
font-size:22px;
font-weight:bold;
padding-left:15px;
}

.main_heading1{
color:#740a07;
font-size:22px;
font-weight:bold;
padding-left:25px;
margin-top:-18px;
}

#business_image{
width:154px;
height:100px;
float:right;
margin:auto;
}

#des{
width:290px;
height:73px;
float:left;
margin:auto;
}

#des p{
color:#4b4d4f;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:justify;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
margin-top:4px;
}

.read_more a{
color:#740a07;
font-size:15px;
text-decoration:none;
float:right;
margin-top:-20px;
font-weight:bold;
padding-right:10px;
}

.read_more a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}

#business_planning{
width:290px;
height:173px;
float:left;
margin-left:5px;
background-color:#d7d4c5;
}

#content_bottom{
width:880px;
float:left;
margin-bottom:15px;
}

#content_bottom_left{
width:600px;
float:left;
margin:auto;
}

#content_bottom_intro{
width:600px;
float:left;
margin:auto;
}

.content_heading{
background-image:url(images/heading_bg.gif);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:202px;
height:36px;
color:#FFFFFF;
padding-left:15px;
padding-top:5px;
}

#content_bottom_intro p{
font-size:15px;
text-align:justify;
margin-top:-10px;
}

#partners{
width:600px;
float:left;
margin:auto;
}

#partners h3{
color:#4d4c49;
font-size:22px;
}

#partners_logo{
width:600px;
height:150px;
float:left;
margin-top:-10px;
border:1px #666666 solid;
}

#content_bottom_right{
width:260px;
float:right;
margin:auto;
}

#right_content{
width:260px;
float:right;
margin:auto;
}

#right_content_detail{
width:255px;
height:162px;
float:left;
margin-top:-10px;
border:1px #666666 solid;
}

#right_content_detail h4{
padding-left:10px;
color:#363430;
margin-top:5px;
}

.post{
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
margin-left:10px;
}

#right_content_detail p{
margin-top:-12px;
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:5px;
color:#363430;
font-size:14px;
text-align:justify;
}

#right_content_detail ul{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

#right_content_detail ul li{
float:left;
display:block;v
}

#right_content_detail ul li a{
font-size:17px;
margin-top:5px;
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
color:#363430;
width:200px;
padding-left:10px;
margin-top:8px;
}

#right_content_detail ul li a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}

.read_more_link a{
color:#740a07;
font-size:15px;
text-decoration:none;
float:right;
font-weight:bold;
padding-right:10px;
padding-top:5px;
}

.read_more_link a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}

.line_bg{
width:600px;
float:left;
margin-top:10px;
}

#footer_bg{
width:900px;
float:left;
margin:auto;
background-color:#2e6a92;
}

#footer{
width:880px;
height:74px;
float:none;
margin:auto;
}

#footer_menu{
width:630px;
height:74px;
float:left;
margin:auto;
}

#footer_menu ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}

#footer_menu ul li{
list-style:none;
float:left;
}

#footer_menu ul li a{
width:100px;
height:23px;
font-size:18px;
display:block;
color:#ffffff;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
text-align:left;
text-decoration:none;
}

#footer_menu ul li a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}


#footer_link{
width:250px;
height:74px;
float:right;
margin:auto;
}

.footer_table{ 
float:right; 
border:none;
margin-top:45px;
}

.footer_td{
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:16px;
}

.link a{
color:#FFFFFF;
text-decoration:none;
}

.link a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: IF we could see the code/website in question, we can could tell you what might be going on. Without these vital pieces of the puzzle anything we say would be mere speculation. Have you tried ctrl+F5?

Comment: Do you mean, you're using child themes?? I'm not aware of a way of theming WP by bypassing the theme system entirely?

Comment: @kyle : code does not matter. The problem is that sometimes when I use a html tag like <br>, <p> , <div>, etc. to make changes through dashboard of wordpress, nothing happens.

Comment: @Ravneet'Abid' Code _does_ matter. If you were to go to a mechanic and tell him that when you turn your key the engine does not start, would you tell him the "car does not matter?" Perhaps your selectors are wrong, maybe there's a caching issue. We have no idea and cannot figure out a vague description of a problem _without seeing some code!_

Comment: @kyle : ok I am going to add code.

Comment: Add more details : How did you build this theme ? What page do you want to modify (home, archive, single...etc) ? Did you read this : http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any cache plugin installed? I had the same issue where my website wouldn't update. I later found out it was a WP SuperCache plugin issue.

Comment: How can I recognize that plugins or file?

Comment: Click on "Plugins" and check if WP Super Cache is on the list.